# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using NativeCSS

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, nativecss

I'm trying to use the `nativecss` library but face the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error. This error only appears when the following style is added:

```
viewcontroller#view { 
-ios-style-guide-visible:true;
}
```

or

```
viewcontroller#view,
viewcontroller#view > view { 
-ios-style-guide-visible:true;
}
```

**edit** or

```
view {
-ncss-style-guide-visible:true;
}
```

also on the error stack mostly it stops around the `property_getAttributes` call

has anyone encounter similar problems?

**update**

My bad:) it seems that it doesnt work on real device, when I've run this code on simulator then all works,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only works on simulator not real device. To have it working test on simulator.